# Sqoop Directory Deleted fron /usr/lib

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, sqoop, bigdata

I am new in Big Data and was doing R&D. I accidentally deleted sqoop directory from hadoop. Is there any way that I can recover it or If I can re-install the directory. Although I downloaded SQOOP and un-tar it, but when I am trying to set the path it is saying that /usr/lib/sqoop doesn't exist. Help is highly appretiated. Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: You question is not clear, If it's a multi node cluster and installed through Cloudera manager, You can try copy /usr/lib/sqoop directory from other servers in the cluster.

Comment: Hi, I am working on my laptop so have a single node cluster. Is there any other way to recover it?

Comment: How did you install sqoop ? , Did you use Cloudera express installer or Did you install through Cloudera rpm ?

Comment: I installed CDH 5.10.1, so sqoop came along with that.